# Partition String C++

Tags: c++, string

I need to find an string with two nested for loops. I am running into logic problems.

One String "California".

Check index from both ends -> <-

if each index character match choose that string.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char stringValue[] = "California";
    string s = stringValue;
    string oreoString = "";


    for(int index = 0; index < s.length(); index++){


        for(int innerIndex = s.length(); innerIndex > 0; innerIndex--){


            if(stringValue[index] == stringValue[innerIndex]){
                oreoString = oreoString + stringValue[index];
            }

        }//End Inner-Loop


    }//End Outer-Loop


    cout << oreoString << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Problem: my output is giving me "aaliiforniiaa"

Comment: Although you provided a couple of examples of *oreo strings*, it doesn't appear you explained what they were.

Comment: I have edited the output

Comment: You haven't told us what problem you're having. We're not going to just write your code for you.

Comment: `s[s.length()]` is out of bounds of string and Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Is `Declared` an oreo string?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen although `s[s.length()]` is indeed out of bounds, it is not undefined behavior in C++11 and later.  `length()` is the same as `size()`, and when `pos == size()`, C++11 guarantees that `operator[]` returns a reference to a nul character.

Comment: @CoderChick: Clear as mud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{   

    std::string input = "California";

    int a = 0, b = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<input.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j=i; j<input.size(); ++j) {

            if (input[i] == input[j] && (j-i+1) > (b - a + 1)) {
                a = i;
                b = j;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << input.substr(a, b-a+1) << std::endl;
}
```

Here is another O(n) solution (only lowercase input)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{   

    std::string input = "california";
    int longest = 0;
    int a = 0;

    char occ[26]; memset(occ, -1, sizeof(occ));

    for (int i=0; i<input.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (occ[input[i] - 'a'] == -1)
            occ[input[i] - 'a'] = i;

        if (i - occ[input[i] - 'a'] + 1 > longest) {
            longest = i - occ[input[i] - 'a'] + 1;
            a = occ[input[i] - 'a'];
        }

    }

    std::cout << input.substr(a, longest) << std::endl;
}
```